# Вывод COM портов на php

Tags: php, com, arduino, com-порт

Доброго времени суток. Нужно вывести список COM портов посредством php. Надеюсь на ваш ответ.

Comment: Открывайте все файлы с именами COM1-COMn, потом выводите те, что откроются. Но вообще использовать PHP для этих целей - неблагодарное занятие

Comment: можно уточнение? где находятся эти файлы?)

Comment: Нигде они не находятся. Это специальные имена файлов, которые обрабатывает ОС.

Comment: дошло, спасибо.